# Export access data to excel with category using visual basic

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have this code:

```
@"SELECT * +
@"INTO [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\__tmp\zzzNew.xlsx].[Sheet1] " +
@"FROM SampleData";
```

Where can I add a category when exporting? **i.e.**: `WHERE Date > "& txtDate.text &`

Comment: after `@"From SampleData"` is not working?  i.e.: `@"WHERE CatFoo = 'Kibble'"`?

Comment: ... um, oh.  `txtDate.txt` probably needs to be converted to actual text.  Let me back up.  Are you getting an error code?  What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the WHERE clause to the end of your SQL statement, something like this (in C#, but the VB.NET code would be very similar):

```csharp
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    string txtDate_text = "2013-02-01";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = 
            @"SELECT * " +
            @"INTO [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\__tmp\zzzNew.xlsx].[Sheet1] " +
            @"FROM SampleData " +
            @"WHERE [Date]=?";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtDate_text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```